# send an http request without XHR in an event handler

Tags: javascript, send

How to send an http request with either post/get method using javascript as an eventhandler? Thanks! Paul

Comment: This is called Ajax and Google would have helped you even faster than us ;)

Comment: Sorry I didn't make the question clear: What I tried to do is not using XmlHttpRequest. IS there any other way?

Comment: You can submit a form to send get or post. I added an answer on how to do that.

Comment: that would be form.submit() then. jesus! speak out loud next time!

Comment: sorry guys! I was working very late and not very clear. Let me rephrase my question:
I've got a string and want to use javascript to send the string to the server, but I don't want use an asynchronous request. Is there any way I can do it.

And I think you guys give me a really big help! thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, you don't want to use Ajax. 
You can use an event handler to submit a form!

```
<a href='#' onclick='cow_submit("zoodle")'>send</a>
<form method='post' id='formie' action='find_some_action.php'>
  <input type='hidden' id='snoutvar' name='snoutvar' value='snout'>
</form>

<script>
function cow_submit(a_var_to_set){
  var plip=document.getElementById('formie');
  var snout=document.getElementById('snoutvar');
  snout.value=a_var_to_set;
  plip.submit();
  }
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_http.asp) for sending request from javascript

Sending GET request

```
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("GET", url+"?"+params, true);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(null);
```

Sending POST request

```
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

And don't forget to encode parameters using `encodeURIComponent` for param value encoding in case of user input

e.g.

```
params="paramName="+encodeURIComponent(paramValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [XmlHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/)

sample code:

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.onreadystatechange = handler;
client.open("GET", "test.xml");
client.send();

function handler()
{
   // your handler
}
```

Comment: How this is not an XHR?

Answer (score 1):

The standard class for doing this is `XmlHttpRequest`, but it's not universally supported.  On some browsers you have to use `ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` instead.

Look into the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) system which provides HTTP download (AJAX style) methods regardless of the underlying browser APIs (hence avoiding a lot of the code shown in Tzury's answer).

The jQuery AJAX documentation is at http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax

Answer (score 1):

You should try to add atring in a hidden field and then call the form.submit() to submit your form into the page define in action.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doTestFormSubmit(yourString) {
    document.getElementById("myString").value=myString;
    document.getElementById("testForm").submit();
  }
</script>
<form name="testForm" id="testForm" action="yourDesiredPage.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="myString" id="myString" value=""/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Tutorial (http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/ajax-tutorial.html)

```
var obj;

function ProcessXML(url) {
  // native  object

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // obtain new object
    obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // set the callback function
    obj.onreadystatechange = processChange;
    // we will do a GET with the url; "true" for asynch
    obj.open("GET", url, true);
    // null for GET with native object
    obj.send(null);
  // IE/Windows ActiveX object
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    if (obj) {
      obj.onreadystatechange = processChange;
      obj.open("GET", url, true);
      // don't send null for ActiveX
      obj.send();
    }
  } else {
    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX");
  }
}


function processChange() {
    // 4 means the response has been returned and ready to be processed
    if (obj.readyState == 4) {
        // 200 means "OK"
        if (obj.status == 200) {
            // process whatever has been sent back here:
        // anything else means a problem
        } else {
            alert("There was a problem in the returned data:\n");
        }
    }
}
```