# How to create a xmlhttp request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var url="display.php?vote="+grade; 
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged 
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
xmlHttp.send(null)
}
}

function stateChanged() 
{ 
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
 { 
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText 
 } 
}
```

This piece of code fails to send out the request. How to create a `xmlHttp` correctly?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620305/send-an-http-request

Comment: Retagged `js` to `javascript` as it has much higher coverage.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
else
  {
  alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
  }
}
</script>
```

this piece of code is available in [link text](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/) you can learn basics here like i did. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "80%" solution.

```
function GetXHR()
{
  try
  {
    if (window.XmlHTTPRequest)
      xmlHttp = new XmlHTTPRequest()
    else
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
  }
  catch(e) { }
}

var xmlHttp = GetXHR()
if (xmlHttp)
{
    // Proceed with xmlHttp usage.
}
```

**Edit**

Note I tend to avoid the old ProgID "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" in favour of the one I have used because this later ProgID has a more predictable behaviour and is ever so slightly more secure.  However if you want wider compatiblity with really old Windows machines (I'm talking out-of-support stuff) then you could use the older one in your specific case.

Comment: @Mask:  Actually its more like 99% but I'm refering to the "80/20" rule.  This small chunk of code (the 20% of effort) solves the problem for the vast majority of cases (the 80%).  In fact it will work on all common browsers.  It would fail on say a vanilla Windows 95 machine running IE5.

Answer (score 0):

`var xmlHttp=new(window.ActiveXObject?ActiveXObject:XMLHttpRequest)('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');`